# Is Scala MongoDB driver available as a dependency?

Tags: mongodb, scala

Reading the instructions for the Scala MongoDB driver at : https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/scala/ it points to the GitHub page : 
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver

But there doesn't seem to be a sbt dependency ?

To use the Scala driver do I need to build the project from GitHub and include it in my project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "binaries" section of the readme says"

"Binaries and dependency information for Maven, SBT, Ivy and others can be found at [http://search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Aorg.mongodb.scala)"

Click on the version you want and get a page like [this](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.mongodb.scala%7Cmongo-scala-driver_2.11%7C1.1.0%7Cjar)